# How to create JSON dynamically in proper json format and keep appending new data to the same object?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a form in which user enters email and password and on submitting, JSON is being created dynamically. When I login again with another user details, the same JSON gets updated, but with new object and thus my JSON gets corrupted.
Below is the JS function Used to create JSON - 
`var g_objJSON = {};

```
    /** setJSON - Create JSON object
    * Returns - Nothing
    **/
    function setJSON() {
        var v_aJSON = [];
        var v_hObject = {};
        var v_hTempHash = {};

        var v_sKey = document.getElementById("user_email").value;
 // v_sKey = $_SESSION['user_email'];
        var v_sValue = document.getElementById("user_password").value;

        try {
            v_hObject[v_sKey] = v_sValue;

            document.getElementById("user_email").value = "";
            document.getElementById("user_password").value = "";

            if (g_objJSON == undefined) {
                v_aJSON.push(v_hObject);
            } else {
                v_hTempHash = mergeHashOb(g_objJSON[0], v_hObject);
      v_aJSON.push(v_hTempHash);
            }
    g_objJSON = v_aJSON;
    alert("Account successfully created!");
    for (var item in g_objJSON[0]) {
        console.log("Email: " + item + "\nPassword: " +   g_objJSON[0][item]);
        $.ajax({
          url: "/open day planner/json.php",
          type: 'POST',
          data: {json: JSON.stringify(g_objJSON)},
          dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
        } catch (x) {
            alert(x.message);
  }
}
/** mergeHashOb - Merge a new JSON object with the global JSON object
           * @prm_hObj - Existing Hash object
           * @prm_hObj2 - New Hash object
           * Returns - A new Hash object contains the merged Hash objects
           **/
           function mergeHashOb(prm_hObj, prm_hObj2) {
                   var v_hObj = {};
                   for (var item in prm_hObj2) { 
                           v_hObj[item] = prm_hObj2[item]; 
                   }
                   return v_hObj;
           }`
```

json.php:
`

```
<?php
   $json = $_POST['json'];

   /* sanity check */
   if (json_decode($json) != null)
   {
     $file = fopen('new_account_data.json','a');
     fwrite($file, $json);
     fclose($file);
   }
   else
   {
     // handle the error 
   }
?>
```

`

JSON output:
`[{"c.harlie@gmail.com":"zxcvb"}][{"vrishgarg@xxxx.com":"vrish"}]`

Expected output:
`[{"c.harlie@gmail.com":"zxcvb"},
{"vrishgarg@xxxx.com":"vrish"}]`

Comment: Do yourself and your audience a favor. Edit your question and discuss what you found when you single-stepped through the code with the debugger. People will be able to help you more effectively if they know everything you know about the problem.

Comment: don't just append, parse the json inside the file into a php object, and then append to that object, and you can now write it again to the file.

Comment: @Wreigh Hi, Can you please explain more how to do that programmatically?

Comment: Hi @Wreigh Just on top of this, if I want a key to be added for email and value as password, how can I add that to my json? For example - [{"email": "vrish@xxx.com", "password": "vrishxxx"}]

Comment: Have to add this in php file?

Answer (score 0):

You should **take** the json out of the file, and **actually** append to that json, not to the file's contents. I believe something like this will get you started to what you want to happen.

```
<?php
    // let's parse this right away
    $json = json_decode($_POST['json']);

    /* sanity check */
    if ($json != null)
    {
      // parse the file contents to json
      $fileContents = file_get_contents('new_account_data.json');
      $parsedJson = json_decode($fileContents);

      if ($parsedJson === null) {
        // it's either the file contains bad json or it is empty (tested with 7.1)
        $parsedJson = array();
      }

      // append your new data to the parsed json
      // I'm assuming the $_POST['json'] returns a stringified array, I'll take the first element and append it.
      $parsedJson[] = $json[0];
      // now write to the file
      $file = fopen('new_account_data.json','w'); // note that we're writing, not appending.
      // write to file the json_encoded $parsedJson
      fwrite($file, json_encode($parsedJson));
      fclose($file);
    }
    else
    {
      // handle the error 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Not getting  anything now. Nothing being appended. Tried `$file = fopen('new_account_data.json','a');` instead of `$file = fopen('new_account_data.json','w');` , but no change.

Comment: can you `var_dump($parsedJson)` after appending `$json` to it?

Comment: I've updated my answer to handle empty file or file that contains bad json.

Comment: This gives me JSON output as : `["["]`

Comment: make sure you did this at the top `$json = json_decode($_POST['json']);`

Comment: Yup, doing as above, but sorry to say that it's giving me the output as mentioned in the question as before. `[{"c.harlie@gmail.com":"zxcvb"}][{"vrishgarg@xxxx.com":"vrish"}]`

Comment: I've tried it in sandbox php and it is working. try to see the latest update of my answer.

Comment: here: https://pastebin.com/JwFu0dff try to execute that in http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com

Comment: You're a genius. That's totally working for me..thanks a lot!

Comment: yeah, i did but it's not accepting because of less reputations. I will, once I have enough for sure!! Ca't thank you enough.

Comment: Just on top of this, if I want a key to be added for email and value as password, how can I add that to my json?

Comment: For example - `[{"email": "vrish@xxx.com", "password": "vrishxxx"}]`

Comment: since you're getting an array of objects from the file, and you have already parsed the file content into an actual object in php, you can just create another property for the object, say: `$parsedJson[0]->email = 'sample@gmail.com';`. In JSON, `{}` is an object and `[]` is an array.

Comment: How do I add that dynamically? in php file?

Comment: yes, in php file. you can dynamically add properties to an object.

Comment: Can you please show me how to add two properties against the email and password generated before for this php file? Or can we do that in the JS file?

Comment: i do not understand your
 questions, furthermore, you can just create a new question since this is getting far from your original question. *However*, to answer your question, it's either change the format of the data you send to php or change the way you handle data sent from html.